# Sketch 3 curved arrows

Tags: vector, sketch-app

Is it possible to create curved (non-straight) arrows in Sketch 3?
Im drawing some phases with arrows showing iterations, so I need half-circle shaped arrows going back to previous phases, etc..
Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Next question.

Answer (score 12):

Two options:

1. Draw an arrow. Double click on it. Edit the nodes to make it curved.
2. Draw a curved line. Add arrowhead in the border options panel.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a little old but here is an easy approach to this making a curved arrow. Say you want your arrow to pop up vertical then off to the right. Draw that out with your pen tool. Then, grab the point where the line turns 90 degrees and change the corner radius and it will bevel the line.

**To make that arrow responsive:**
Now for the arrow part. Draw that out and position it. Group all parts, Go into your resizing drop down and pin that arrow head. Now you can resize your arrow which lets you reuse it.